# What are the connections on this German TV socket?

Tags: television

I live in Germany. I have zero knowledge in TVs. I found a TV socket in the wall but I have no idea what it means.

My questions is: can you please explain to me what does each port in the socket does?

Here I attach a picture for the socket:

[image]

**EDIT: Is it called DVB-T?**

Comment: Your simplest and probably cheapest option is to buy a used TV.

Comment: Your laptop is not a television, TV's contain tuners to tune in a channel being broadcast. You can buy these for computers, but that conversation off topic for the site.

Answer (score 1):

> can you please explain to me what does each port in the socket does?

In your photo they are labelled DATA, TV, R

So it is reasonable to assume

- DATA: DOCSIS connection, you can use it to connect to the internet if you purchase a data plan from your cable television provider
- TV: A TV antenna.
- R: A Radio antenna.

Nowadays the TV signal is likely to be DVB-T. The antenna and coaxial cable and connectors are the same as for the old analogue PAL signals. It is possible that it is DVB-S from a satellite dish. I'd ask the building manager (if there is one).

Answer (score 1):

The data port is a satellite feed from your dish, or if it's a shared complex, it's a satellite feed. You may or may not require a decoder for the satellite depending on the setup. Data in this case actually means it's a digital connection.

The only problem with this fixture is that hd satellite may require multiple feeds to the HD receiver, (TiVo and pvr stuff)

The TV port is a the old school tv antenna port where you have the rf antenna on the roof. You will need to scan for open air channels from your TV with this analog connection

Radio is just connected to a radio antenna or mast.